# LogisticRegression MemoryError

Tags: python, memory, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am using a Logistic Regression to train a model on some textual data. Here is the code I use:

```
from fonduer.learning import LogisticRegression
disc_model = LogisticRegression()
%time disc_model.train((train_cands[0], F_train[0]), train_marginals, n_epochs=50, lr=0.001)
```

The code doesn't have any problem when I run it on 20 Docs but when I increase the number of Docs to 40 I get this error:

```
[INFO] fonduer.learning.disc_learning - Load defalut parameters for Logistic Regression

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed eval> in <module>

~/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fonduer/learning/disc_learning.py in train(self, X_train, Y_train, n_epochs, lr, batch_size, rebalance, X_dev, Y_dev, print_freq, dev_ckpt, dev_ckpt_delay, save_dir, seed, host_device)
    169 
    170         _X_train, _Y_train = self._preprocess_data(
--> 171             X_train, Y_train, idxs=train_idxs, train=True
    172         )
    173         if X_dev is not None:

~/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fonduer/learning/disc_models/logistic_regression.py in _preprocess_data(self, X, Y, idxs, train)
     59         C, F = X
     60         if issparse(F):
---> 61             F = F.todense()
     62 
     63         if idxs is None:

~/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in todense(self, order, out)
    844             `numpy.matrix` object that shares the same memory.
    845         """
--> 846         return np.asmatrix(self.toarray(order=order, out=out))
    847 
    848     def toarray(self, order=None, out=None):

~/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in toarray(self, order, out)
    945         if out is None and order is None:
    946             order = self._swap('cf')[0]
--> 947         out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
    948         if not (out.flags.c_contiguous or out.flags.f_contiguous):
    949             raise ValueError('Output array must be C or F contiguous')

~/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)
   1182             return out
   1183         else:
-> 1184             return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
   1185 
   1186 

MemoryError:
```

Comment: Well this means you just run out of memory. Could you provide your machine setup (RAM etc.) and size of docs?

Comment: Could you also show the size of F by doing `print(F.size)` and `print(F.dtype)`

Comment: Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 16,0 GB
Total Physical Memory 16,0 GB
Available Physical Memory 9,15 GB
Total Virtual Memory 18,3 GB
Available Virtual Memory 10,2 GB

Comment: size = 6347423 and type = float64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the feature size was too large for `LogisticRegression`. I replaced `LogisticRegression` with `SparseLogisticRegression` and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DASK package. It is used for large datasets if memory is less. You will be able load a larger dataset than memory itself.